# Java/JDBC - Using TableModels to display individual data

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

My hobby-level programing won't let me extend my program the way I want to, and my books/google won't help me out too much, hopefully you guys can!

I'm writing a simple database viewing program using the 'ResultSetTableModel' to import data from my local mySQL database.
The current program displays the entries in a nice list, and all of the data contained in each entry is presented as an individual cell in the JTable.

However, I now want to implement a feature to the JTable rows, that 'on click' displays the content (in my case an image using an image path)
However, after trying endlessly I cannot seem to find an easy and short way to add an eventhandler that does this for me.

I've managed to do similar things with manually populated tables before, but when trying to apply the lessons learned there to this new project gets me nowhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add a ListSelectionListener to the the table selectionmodel:

```
table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
          // Last selected row:
          table.getSelectedRow(); // -1 if no row selected
          // All selected rows:
          table.getSelectedRows();

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,

When trying to apply this to my prog getSelectionModel gets redlined, prompting for a metod in the ResultSetTableModel (I've split the program across classes)

Comment: @Bittein What do you mean it gets red-lined? Do you mean that your IDE says that this call is not valid? Here `table` is a `JTable` and this call is valid: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Comment: I was targeting the model, not the table, sorry my bad, trying the code now

Comment: Your code is working as intended! Thank you, may I also ask you how the clicked row is returned? (As in 'I want to know what row was clicked')

Comment: @Bittein I edited my answer to show how to find the selected row(s). After that you can interrogate your model to see what "Model Object" it represents.

Comment: Thank you, you have been very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `MouseListener` (or `MouseAdapter`) to the the table - e.g.

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
  @Override
  public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    // do something cool...
  }
}
```